# spark2.0 dataframe collect muilt row as array by column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have some dataframe like below, i want convert muilt row  as an array if column value is the same

```
val data = Seq(("a","b","sum",0),("a","b","avg",2)).toDF("id1","id2","type","value2").show
    +---+---+----+------+
    |id1|id2|type|value2|
    +---+---+----+------+
    |  a|  b| sum|     0|
    |  a|  b| avg|     2|
    +---+---+----+------+
```

i want to convert it to below

```
+---+---+----+------+
|id1|id2|agg |value2|
+---+---+----+------+
|  a|  b| 0,2|     0|
+---+---+----+------+
```

the printSchema should be like below

```
root
 |-- id1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- agg: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sum: int (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dc: int (nullable = true)
```

Comment: what is value2 in 2nd table?   I mean how the value2 is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = Seq(
  ("a","b","sum",0),("a","b","avg",2)
).toDF("id1","id2","type","value2")

val result = data.groupBy($"id1", $"id2").agg(struct(
  first(when($"type" === "sum", $"value2"), true).alias("sum"), 
  first(when($"type" === "avg", $"value2"), true).alias("avg")
).alias("agg"))

result.show

+---+---+-----+   
|id1|id2|  agg|
+---+---+-----+
|  a|  b|[0,2]|
+---+---+-----+

result.printSchema
root
 |-- id1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- agg: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- sum: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- avg: integer (nullable = true)
```